# Totals Block does not show in Order Summary in Checkout Page;Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, order-summary

In Order Summary block(Checkout Page), totals block is missing. In the Cart Page, totals block is displayed.
[image]

I have to override `checkout_cart_index.xml` in my theme for Cart
 Page. The code in `checkout_cart_index.xml` is:

[image]

My console has Js errors. I have jquery.min.js version 1.12.4(Default one) in my theme.[image]
1. Are these JS errors responsible for my issue?

2. Why do I get totals block in Cart Page but not in Checkout Page?

Can you please guide me to bring back my Totals block. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Total is display on Payment page not on shipping.
There are two changes required to display summary in shipping step.
Override both files in your current theme.

**1.** change `/Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total.js` file

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals, stepNavigator) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
            },
            getTotals: function() {
                return totals.totals();
            },
            isFullMode: function() {
                if (!this.getTotals()) {
                    return false;
                }
                //return stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping'); // comment this line to enable right side bar in checkout shipping step.  
                return true; //add this line to display forcefully summary in shipping step.
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Now order summary will be displayed in shipping step.

2. change `/Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping.js` file
   This change is for **to update shipping charge in the selection of shipping methods.**

Change **`getValue()`** function.

```
 getValue: function () {
            var price;

            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return this.notCalculatedMessage;
            }
            //var price =  this.totals().shipping_amount; //comment this line

           var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod(); //add these both line
              var price =  shippingMethod.amount; // update data on change of the shipping method

            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        }
```

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: After this is added the total price won't update, do you have an idea how to get that to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's normal. Total should be displayed on checkout second step (Review & Payments). Did you check it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @janZaba.Ya.In second Page of Checkout,I get my totals block. But,I need Totals block to display in (First Page)Checkout.How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

this is the full solution you need to modify 3 files

shipping.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/estimate-service' // <--- add this 
], function ($, Component, quote, estimateService) { // <--- add the last param
....

 getValue: function () {
        var price;

        if (!this.isCalculated()) {
            return this.notCalculatedMessage;
        }
        //var price =  this.totals().shipping_amount; //comment this line

       var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod(); //add these both line
          var price =  shippingMethod.amount; // update data on change of the shipping method

        return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
    }
```

abstract-total.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function (Component, quote, stepNavigator) { 
...

isFullMode: function () {
        if (!this.getTotals()) {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
```

grand-total.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function (Component, quote,stepNavigator) {
..
 getValue: function () {
    
        //
          var totals = quote.getTotals();
            if(typeof(quote.shippingMethod()) != "undefined" && quote.shippingMethod() !== null) {
            var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();
            var price =  shippingMethod.amount;
        }
            var plus = "";
            var minus = "";
        if(totals['base_shipping_amount'] < price){
            plus = totals['base_shipping_amount'] + price;
            return this.getFormattedPrice((this.getPureValue() + price));
        } else if(totals['base_shipping_amount'] > price){
            minus = totals['base_shipping_amount'] - price;
            return this.getFormattedPrice((this.getPureValue() - minus));
        }
        
        
        return this.getFormattedPrice(this.getPureValue());
        }
```

Clear Magento cache and check.